# Angular 6 http service best practice

Tags: angular, angular6

i have a feed service in angular that calls a REST endpoint which returns a List of EntryDTO. Here is how the service looks like:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
export class FeedService() {
  getPublicFeedEntries: Observable<EntryDTO[]> () {
    return this.http.get('/rest/publicFeedEntries/).map((response: Response) => response.json()).catch((err: any) => Observable.throw(error.josn().error || 'error');
  }
}
```

So then i could have a feed component that subscribes to this observable:

```
export class FeedComponent() {
private feedEntries: EntryDTO[];
constructor(private feedService: FeedService) { feedEntries = new Array(); }

ngOnInit() {
  this.feedService.getPublicFeedEntries.subscribe(entries => {
  this.feedEntries = entries;
  }, err => {console.log(err) })
 }
}
```

Is this considered as best practice to return the observable in the service and subscribe in the component or are there other best practices?

Comment: Yes, normally the services return observables and in the component we subscribe to this observables. NOTE: If you use httpClient NOT use map(res=>res.json(). You need't do it

Comment: How do i get the json representation then? otherwise i cant assign the response to my array, right?

Comment: HttpClient, by defect, give you the json object directly. (use a console.log(res) to check it)

Comment: thats nice...:)

Comment: You should also consider using `.pipe(takeUntil( /* Subject */))`. I usually have a property `destroyed$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();` and call `this.destroyed$.next()` in the `ngOnDestroy` hook. This will stop the subscription once the component is destroyed and will stop any subscription leaking which might affect performance.

Comment: That's great. But as Eliseo and Baruch said, no need of Map to json in httpclient. And consider unsubscribing to the observable on the ngDestroy hook.

Comment: @Baruch whats this? I never heard of this, despite i developed plenty productive angular apps :o

Comment: @ItFreak  yea, you're doing it wrong. Here, you can read more about it in [this](https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/) article.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are following is perfectly fine but to take it to new level you can introduce model's in your service which will make the response easy to read/use in your components.

Check this article written on [ngx-model](https://blog.angularindepth.com/model-pattern-for-angular-state-management-6cb4f0bfed87) which provides way to follow a models driven approach in your application.